# Nested for loops python DNS programming

Tags: python, dns

I am trying to loop through two lists in order to get web server IP resolutions from DNS servers. I am trying to figure out how to get the IP resolution from each url with each DNS server IP. The code I have works but I am just trying to figure out how to loop through both of these lists so I don't have to manually enter the index of the list each time I run the code.

```
url = ["www.facebook.com","www.google.com","www.uiowa.edu"] #list of urls                              
ips = ["168.1.79.229","156.154.70.1","138.197.25.214","94.206.181.22","122.176.20.6","217.73.226.120","27.34.140.46","110.165.44.152","187.86.59.3","128.255.1.3"]

clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
message = create_DNS_query(url[i])
clientSocket.sendto(message, (ips[i], 53))
rMessage, address = clientSocket.recvfrom(1000)
ip = decode_dns_message(rMessage)
print ip
clientSocket.close()
```

Comment: Sorry about the second list not being formatted as code I couldn't figure that out for some reason

Comment: Just indent it 4 spaces like everything else

Comment: What you call URLs are actually domain names (a URL starts with a protocol and looks like `http://example.org/foo/bar`). But more importantly, what is the expected output of your program? Have you already written the functions `create_DNS_query` and `decode_dns_message`?

Comment: Sorry if the description was unclear, the functions are sending a message with the domain name to a DNS server which are the IP addresses in the "ips" list and the DNS server is sending a response with the IP address for the web server of that domain name. Also yes the functions have already been written and I am calling them here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just nest your loops, as you say in the title:

```
for name in url:
    for dns in ips:
        clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
        message = create_DNS_query(name)
        clientSocket.sendTo(message, dns, 53)
        rMessage, address = clientSocket.recvfrom(1000)
        ip = decode_dns_message(rMessage)
        print "Server: {} Name: {} IP: {}".format(dns, name, ip)
        clientSocket.close
```

Comment: Will this work if I need to check each host name with each ip?

Comment: That's exactly what it does.